# change JSON to String in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I got JSON file from API but the content looks like this:

```
[
  "https:\/\/seekingalpha.com\/article\/4125943-apple-homepod-delay-big-deal?source=feed_symbol_AAPL"
]
```

Suppose the JSON Object above is named as `json`. Then I just convert the object to string using `String()` method.
  `strings = String(json)`

When I changed it to `String` type, it seems to get unnecessary `'\n'` and `whitespace` in it.

```
"[\n  \"https:\\/\\/seekingalpha.com\\/article\\/4125943-apple-homepod-delay-big-deal?source=feed_symbol_AAPL\"\n]"
```

So it seems like the content of the JSON file is:

`["\n""whitespace""whitespace""String""\n"]`

When I changed it to String type, Swift just treats all the elements in it as a whole and wrapped it as a string.
My question is, how to extract the `String` inside so it looks like:

```
"https:\\/\\/seekingalpha.com\\/article\\/4125943-apple-homepod-delay-big-deal?source=feed_symbol_AAPL\"
```

As I am not so familiar with Swift so how to extract `String` or JSON Object is not easy for me. Any hints or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show some code on how you are trying to convert it to a string.

Comment: By using `String()` method and I have updated above.

Comment: Why would you convert your JSON to String in the first place? You don't need to do that. Just decode the JSON *data* using one of the usual tools: JSONSerialization, SwiftyJSON, JSON Decoder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 3,4 :**

The given JSON format is `Array` of `String`.

```
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String]{

        let firstElement = json?.first ?? "Element Not Found!"

        print(firstElement)
}
```

**Swift 4:**

```
if let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Array<String>.self, from: data){

    let firstElement = json.first ?? "First Element Not Found!"
    print(firstElement)
}
```

**Note:** 
 If your the `Array` contains more than one `String`. Here,`urls` is the `class` variable. i.e.,`var urls = [String]()`

**Swift 3,4 :**

```
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String]{

    if json != nil{

        self.urls = json!
    }

    print(self.urls)
}
```

**Swift 4:**

```
if let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Array<String>.self, from: data){

    self.urls = json
}
```

Comment: Really informative answer, I appreciate it!!!! Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
1. You will first have to convert JSON to Data
2. Convert data to string wrt to encoding    

    func jsonToString(jsonTOConvert: AnyObject){
        do {
            let data =  try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonTOConvert, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) 
            let convertedString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) 
        } catch let myJSONError {
            print(myJSONError)
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking that a `String` be created with the contents:

```
[
  "https:\/\/seekingalpha.com\/article\/4125943-apple-homepod-delay-big-deal?source=feed_symbol_AAPL"
]
```

The string object is doing exactly what you told it to — the thing you've asked it to represent begins with a square bracket, then there's a line break, then two spaces, etc, so the string contains a square bracket, then a line break, then two spaces, etc. There is no 'unnecessary' `\n`, there is only the `\n` you told it to put in.

If you obtained a JSON object then you need to parse it as JSON. `JSONSerialization` will do that job. What you've actually got is an array with a single item, which is a string. So `JSONSerialization` will return an array. The first item of that should be a string that is the seekingalpha.com URL.

Comment: Got it. Many Thanks:)